# Load file content into nifi attribute using executescript

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I'm trying to load the contents of a file into an attribute and preface it with "Bearer ". This is how far I got:

```
def flowFile = session.get();
if (flowFile != null) {

    def token = flowFile.getAttribute("token")
    def message = "Bearer " + token
    flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "message", message)
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
}
```

However I'm stuck trying to load file contents rather than using .getattribute. Can anyone please help me?

**EDIT: To confirm, this is to load the contents of a txt file.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use `ExecuteGroovyScript` with following code to read flowfile content and put it into an attribute:

```
def ff = session.get()
if(!ff)return

ff.message = "Bearer " + ff.read().getText("UTF-8")
REL_SUCCESS << ff
```

to read usual file just replace `ff.read().getText("UTF-8")`

with `new File("path/to/file.txt").getText("UTF-8")`

---

NOTE: beware to store large values into attributes.

Comment: Hi Daggett, thank you so much for this. Can I please ask, where am I meant to be defining the location of the file, is it like this? ff.read(path/to.file.txt)...

Comment: ah. you mean file (not the flow file)

Comment: Sorry yes I wasn't clear, I mean from a text file, read the entire content into a flowfile attribute. The content of the file will always be very small.

Comment: modified the answer

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Could I trouble you for a quick question. If I need my attribute to be jwt_token, I thought I would just change it to ff.jwt_token, but that stops it working. Any idea why?

Comment: Should work. But be sure you are using ExecuteGroovyScript (not ExecuteScript)

Comment: it doesn’t like the underscore but I found a way around it, thank yoy

Answer (score 2):

You need to call session.read with the flow file and an InputStreamCallback.

There is an example here:

https://funnifi.blogspot.com/2016/08/executing-remote-commands-in-nifi-with.html